# Get a list of all Oracle data sources via DBI

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi

I'm creating a perl program where the user has to enter the name of a database, in addition to a username and password, and the program connects to that database using `DBI->connect`. What I'd like to do is to have the program present a list of names of databases that it can connect to, and all the user has to do is input their username and password, for ease of use. I took a look at the [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#data_sources) for data sources, thinking it was what I need but when I call `DBI->data_sources('Oracle')` it doesn't return anything (but no errors are encountered either). I don't see how this can happen, as the program is able to connect without any hitches if the user supplies the database name. Is there something that I'm doing wrong, or something that I'm not getting?

And yes, I realize I can just manually open the tnsnames.ora file and parse that. In fact, that's what I did first but I'd like to use DBI preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;

my @drivers = DBI->available_drivers();

die "No drivers found!\n" unless @drivers; # should never happen

foreach my $driver ( @drivers ) {
    print "Driver: $driver\n";
    my @dataSources = DBI->data_sources( $driver );
    foreach my $dataSource ( @dataSources ) {
        print "\tData Source is $dataSource\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Four things are printed: dbi::ODBC:dBASE Files, dbi:ODBC:Excel Files, dbi:ODBC:MS Access Database, dbi:ODBC:Xtreme Sample Database 2005

Comment: Do you know if you have any DBI modules installed?  I would try this too: my $length = @dsns and see what that returns

Comment: Did you just now change it to ODBC?  And are you trying to install an Oracle driver?

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my first post because your code was exactly what I had done, except I had 'Oracle' instead of 'ODBC' so I assumed they were the same because I didn't notice the difference. :S And I'm not trying to install anything; everything is already in place and I'm able to already connect to the Oracle databases.

Comment: Have you answered your own question then?  Do you need any more help?

Comment: No, my problem is that DBI->data_sources('Oracle') doesn't return anything, even though I'm able to connect to the oracle databases if the user supplies the database name. Is there a problem in my understanding of what DBI->data_sources does, or is it something else?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I guess my understanding is at fault, and the confusing wording on the DBI documentation (data_sources - Returns a list of data sources (databases) available via the named driver) is what got me. I guess I'll use perl's best feature and parse the tnsnames.ora file manually; thanks!

Comment: Very few DBDs can return a list of valid data sources to connect to. DBD::ODBC can do this because ODBC has an API to enumerate DSNs which basically reads them from the registry or your odbc.ini file.